# Create two navigation link for single table in rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have one table named **User**.

In that i have two type of record :

1) Corporation

2) Agency

Field name is is_agency?(Boolean). If is agency then true and if is corporation then false.

I want to display **User** table to two different table **Corporation** and **Agency** in admin side. I used rails_admin gem.

How can i differentiate using "is_agency?" field ?

I check rails_admin gem documentation but i did't find any thing about this.

Please help me to find out this solution, it will save my hours.

Answer (score 0):

you can crate a custom action as described here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

for example

```
# in lib/rails_admin/agency.rb

require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
module RailsAdmin
   module Config
      module Actions
         class Agency < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
         RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
         register_instance_option :controller do
            Proc.new do
               @objects = Project.where(is_agency: true)
               render "index"
            end
         end
         register_instance_option :collection do
            true
          end
         register_instance_option :link_icon do
            'icon-th-list'
         end 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you have to add it to the rails_admin.rb initializer

```
config.actions do
dashboard                     # mandatory
index 
agency do
  only ['User']
end
```

Then do the same for Corporation.

Do not forget to add the translations to locales rails_admin.en.yml

Another way to do it is using scopes:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List
Search for scopes in the text.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Ioannis